# How to use custom font special symbols in object properties used in React Component

Tags: reactjs, fonts

I am using a custom font (https://github.com/geordanr/xwing-miniatures-font) for a React App that generates information for a board game. I am storing the data I use in an frozen object located in a separate class:

```
{
    TIELN: {
        name: "Tie-Fighter",
        initiative: 2,
        shields: 0,
        hull: 3,
        attack: 2,
        agility: 3,
        id: "TIELN",
        selTarget: ["Nearest enemy ship in your firing arc.", "Nearest enemy ship."],
    },
    TIEIN: {
        name: "Tie-Interceptor",
        initiative: 2,
        shields: 0,
        hull: 3,
        attack: 3,
        agility: 3,
        id: "TIEIN",
        selTarget: ["Nearest enemy ship in your firing arc.", "Nearest enemy ship."]
    },
    TIESA: {
        name: "Tie-Bomber",
        initiative: 2,
        shields: 0,
        hull: 6,
        attack: 2,
        agility: 2,
        id: "TIESA",
        selTarget: ["Locked enemy ship at range 1-3", "Nearest enemy ship in your firing arc.", "Nearest enemy ship."]
    }...
```

I need to use the special symbols from the custom font to be desplayed in text that is stored in values of the object (e.g. `selTarget`). The only way I know I can use to achieve that is to use HTML tags (the authors of the font suggest using classes enclosed in a .css file), ReactJS escapes the html symbols (XSS). I know that I can bypass the security by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - but is there a better way around in this scenario?

Comment: Does the custom font need to appear witihn the "selTarget" body in an arbitrary position? In other words, would a "selTarget" value need to be something like- "Locked enemy ship <span class='xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-hit'></span>at range 1-3"?

Comment: Unfortunately it is so - arbitrary symbols in arbitrary positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up creating a switch linked to components which contained fully formed html code, however if I needed to expand the code it would probably make sense to use a library like the one suggested by g_param in his answer.

```
export default function ShipActions(props) {
    switch (props.shipId) {
        case Ships.TIEIN.id:
            return <TIEIN/>;
        case Ships.TIELN.id:
            return <TIELN/>;
        case Ships.TIESA.id:
            return <TIESA/>;
        case Ships.VT49.id:
            return <VT49/>;
        default:
            console.log("Component ShipActions didn't recognize shipId: " + props.shipId);
    }
}

const TIELN = () => (
    <ol>
        <li>Remove 1 stress token or take <i className="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-crit"/> action.</li>
        <li><i className="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-barrelroll"/> to avoid target's firing arc and
            still have it in your firing arc.</li>
        <li><i className="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-barrelroll"/> to get target in your firing arc.</li>
        <li><i className="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-focus"/> if you have target in your firing arc.</li>
        <li><i className="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-barrelroll"/> to avoid target's firing arc.</li>
        <li><i className="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-evade"/></li>
    </ol>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ReactHtmlParser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser) library may be helpful for you here. It works by converting each element, attribute, text node, and inline style to the corresponding React components. One of it's main advantages is it avoids the need for the dreaded `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Example usage in a React `render()` function:

```
render() {
  const html = TIESA.selTarget[0];
  return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a great suggestion. If I extend my data I will probably use it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it could be -

1. Split the item from `selTarget` into space-separated words.
2. Make each word a react-element wrapping the word in `span` tag using map. Additionally add spaces aptly for later use in each element.
3. Use this list to insert a custom-font element as jsx-element(`<i class='xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-hit'></i>`) at an apt index.
4. Wrap this array inside `p` tag as `<p>{selTargetWordsArray}</p>`.

And there you have it - a phrase with different words and the custom-fonts intertwined without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.